# Can every positive integer $n > 2$ be written as the sum of $k$ prime numbers?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I immediately see a problem with number $6$, if $1$ is considered non-prime. Are there other numbers that are not possible to write as the sum of $k$ prime numbers?

Note: Prime numbers can be added repeatedly.

Comment: But $6=3+3$ if you allow repeats

Comment: You can write $6$ as $2+2+2$

Comment: What is k? If you’re allowing repeats, then yes. Every even number is the sum of 2s and every odd is the sum of 2s and a 3.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen how foolish one can be :). Please vote to close this question. And yes I'm allowing repeats.

Comment: Instead of deleting the question, just clarify it to fix $k$.  "For a fixed $k$ can every number...."?  This is probably an interesting question.  $k=3$ is the Goldbach Conjecture.

Comment: @B.Goddard Indeed! It will be. But that's not what I wanted to know.

Comment: What are the constraints on $k$? $k > 0$?

Comment: Yes...k is always greater than 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n$ be even. Then $n=\underbrace{2+2+2+\cdots}_{\frac{n}{2} \text{times}}$

Let $n$ be odd. Then $n=\underbrace{2+2+2+\cdots}_{\frac{n-1}{2}-1  \text{ times}}+3$

Answer (score 3):

If you allow repetition, then you can just use the prime factorization to generate the necessary sums, as in the examples in comments.